# Wp forms wpforms()->entry->update not working on page refresh

Tags: posts, wpdb

Wp forms wpforms()->entry->update not working on page refresh , it only works when i do some change in wordpress dashboard (like clearing cache or updating any post) then only it is updating the data to database

```
function test35()
{

         global $wpdb;
     $tablename = $wpdb->prefix."testtable";
    $result = $wpdb->get_results ( "SELECT * FROM  $tablename" );
    foreach ( $result as $print )   {
    

    $entry_id = $print->jobid;
    $field_id = 57;
    include_once 'wpforms/src/Pro/Admin/Entries/Edit.php';
  

    // Get the current entry fields.
    $entry_fields_obj3 = wpforms()->entry->get( $entry_id );
    $entry_fields = wpforms_decode( $entry_fields_obj3->fields );

    
    if ( isset( $entry_fields[ $field_id ] ) ) {
        
        // Update the value of the specific field.
        $entry_fields[ $field_id ]['value'] = '1';
        $entry_fields[ $field_id ]['value_raw'] = '1';// Replace with your new value.
    }

    // Update the entry fields.
    
    $currnt_time = current_time( 'Y-m-d H:i:s' );
   $entry_data = [
                'fields' => wp_json_encode( $entry_fields ),    
                
            ];

            
    
    if(wpforms()->entry->update(
                $entry_id,
                $entry_data,
                '',
                'edit_entry',
                [
                    'cap' => 'edit_entry_single',
                ]
            )){echo "true";}else{echo "false";}
    
  
    
    $entry_fields_obj2 = wpforms()->get( 'entry_fields' );
    $dbdata_result    = $entry_fields_obj2->get_fields(
            [
                'entry_id' => $entry_id,
                'number'   => 1000,
            ]
        );
    
    $dbdata_fields    = [];
        if ( ! empty( $dbdata_result ) ) {
            $dbdata_fields = array_combine( wp_list_pluck( $dbdata_result, 'field_id' ), $dbdata_result );
            $dbdata_fields = array_map( 'get_object_vars', $dbdata_fields );
        }
    
    $dbdata_value_exist  = isset( $dbdata_fields[ $field_id ]['value'] );
    
    $form_id =  $dbdata_fields[1]['form_id'];
    $new_value = '1';
    $currnt_time = current_time( 'Y-m-d H:i:s' );
    
    // Add field data to DB if it doesn't exist and isn't empty.
    if ( ! $dbdata_value_exist) { 
        echo 'true';    
        $entry_fields_obj2->add(
                    [
                        'entry_id' => $entry_id,
                        'form_id'  => (int) $form_id,
                        'field_id' => (int) $field_id,
                        'value'    => $new_value,
                        'date'     => $currnt_time,
                    ]
                );  
    } 
    
    // Update field data in DB if it exists and isn't empty.
            if ( $dbdata_value_exist && $save_field['value'] !== '' ) {
                echo 'true';    
                $entry_fields_obj2->update(
                    (int) $dbdata_fields[ $field_id ]['id'],
                    [
                        'value' => $new_value,
                        'date'  => $currnt_time,
                    ],
                    'id',
                    'edit_entry'
                );
            }


    }

}

 add_action( 'wp', 'test35');
```

Comment: You'll have to ask the plugin's support team about this. Third-party plugin support is [off topic](/help/on-topic) here.

Comment: thanks for reply bro, i will ask plugin's support only